# Is MySQL safe to use for interlocking operations?

Tags: mysql

For the sake of argument take this query:-

```
UPDATE table SET locked=1 WHERE id=10 AND locked=0;
```

In the case that say (in a very terribly designed system) a million servers are racing to 'obtain lock' by carrying out this statement with autocommit at the same time, would we be garunteed that only one server get back a count of 1 for the amount of rows affected?

Comment: Do you really mean servers?

Comment: In my case yes. I am thinking of a case where several servers have the same filesystem mounted and I want to stop other servers writing to the same file. I suppose they are better thought of as clients though, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is a safe assumption that only one client would be able to see "1 row affected," no matter how much contention there is, because either the relevant row(s) (InnoDB, regardless of the setting of autocommit) or the entire table (MyISAM, Memory, Federated) would be automatically locked by the storage engine before the write was made and unlocked after, so even with a perfectly-timed collision, only one thread could "win."